hyperoctahedral group, preliminaries
I am looking for information on the hyperoctahedral group
From what I understand, the hyperoctahedral group is 'the generalized symmetric group' in the case where $m=2$. That is, the hyperoctahedral group = $S(2,n)$.
From what I see about the generalized symmetric group,
$S(1,n)$ permutes the set ${1, 2, 3, \cdots, n}$
ie $$S(1,n)= \hspace{.15cm}\langle(12),(23),\cdots,(n-1 \hspace{.2cm}n)\rangle,$$
It was my intuition that
$S(2,n)$ permutes the set $\{1_a, 2_a, 3_a, \cdots, n_a, 1_b, 2_b, 3_b, \cdots, n_b\}$
ie $$S(2,n)= \hspace{.15cm}\langle(12)_a,(23)_a,\cdots,(n-1\hspace{.2cm}n)_a, (12)_b,(23)_b,\cdots,(n-1\hspace{.2cm}n)_b\rangle$$
but was told this is not the case. Instead, $S(2,n)=\mathbb{Z}_2^n \rtimes S_n$. How then is $S(2,n)$ isomorphic to the signed permutation group?
--Can someone give me some intuition on how this relates to the symmetries of octahedrons and their $n$-dimensional analogues? (For instance, we know that $S(2,n)=\mathbb{Z}_2^n \rtimes S_n$. Since there are 48 symmetries of the octahedron/cube, I assume this is $\mathbb{Z}_2^3\times S_3$ (ie n=3). How does this relate to the symmetries of the cube?)
-- We used the semi-direct product in our definition (which I have no experience with). Can I list the elements as I would have expected to with the direct product (ie $(\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{0},(123)) \in S(2,3)$)?
--- Is it true that $S(2,3)=<(16),(35),(42),(13)(65),(14)(62),(45)(23)>$?
